# Reasons for not using SendMessage() to access UI controls from other threads?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have read that `SendMessage()` should not be used to access UI controls from other threads, but I'm not sure I know why, the only reason that I can think of is since `SendMessage()` is a blocking call, then it could cause a deadlock in certain situations.

But is this the only reason not to use it?

---

**Edit:** This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke) talks about the reasons not to use `SendMessage()` but I don't find it to be very clear (it is intended for .NET).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that what you read was poor advice, or that you misunderstood what you read? There are plenty of scenarios where `SendMessage` is appropriate, and plenty where it is not. It's not really possible for us to enumerate all of them. You need to give your question much more focus.

Comment: @David Heffernan Most of the tutorials that I have read were written by what seems to be credible authors, for example: http://flounder.com/workerthreads.htm, see the section: **Worker threads and the GUI II: Don't touch the GUI**.

Comment: Some things are safe, some not. You need to understand the details rather than following a blanket rule.

Comment: @David Heffernan Hi. Can you recommend a good tutorial(s) to know when `SendMessage` can be used and when it can't.

Comment: @John I doubt there is such a thing. You just need to understand the rules.

Comment: @David Heffernan I am currently learning about the Windows API, and I need to manipulate the UI controls from worker threads. But I don't know what I should learn to understand how I should do that. I mean I should understand what rules?

Comment: @Hans Passant I have no problem not to use `SendMessage()` if I am displaying something to the UI controls. However, what should I do when I want to retrieve for example the content of an `"EDIT"` control, and then do something with this content, the only option I can think of is to ask for the content and then wait until the content is retrieved (which can only be done with `SendMessage()`, or `PostMessage()` and then wait on an event to be signaled when the UI thread has processed the message).

Comment: Well, another classic threading race if you are not very careful.  What do you expect to get back when the user is busy modifying the text content at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is best to keep in mind that the odds that you will write correct code are not very good.  And the generic advice is *don't do it!*  It is *never* necessary, the UI thread of a GUI program in Windows was entirely structured to make it simple to allow code that runs on another thread or inside a process affect the UI of the program.  The point of the message loop, the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  PostMessage() is your weapon to take advantage of it.

Before you forge ahead anyway, start by thinking about a simple problem that's very hard to solve when you use SendMessage.  How do you close a window safely and correctly?

Given is that the exact moment in time that you *need* to close the window is entirely unpredictable and completely out of sync with the execution of your worker thread.  It is the user that closes it, or asks the UI thread to terminate, you need to make sure that the thread has exited and stops calling SendMessage before you can actually close the window.

The intuitive way to do this is to signal an event in your WM_CLOSE message handler, asking the thread to stop.  And wait for it to complete, then the window can close.  Intuitive, but it does not work, it will deadlock your program.  Sometimes, not always, very hard to debug.  Goes wrong when the thread cannot check the event because it is stuck in the SendMessage call.  Which cannot complete since the UI thread is waiting for the thread to exit.  The worker thread cannot continue and the UI thread cannot continue.  A "deadly embrace", your program will hang and needs to be killed forcibly.  Deadlock is a standard threading bug.

You'll shout, "I'll use SendMessageTimeout!"  But what do you pass for the *uTimeout* argument and how do you interpret an ERROR_TIMEOUT error?  It is pretty common for a UI thread to go catatonic for a while, surely you've seen the "ghost window" before, the one that shows 'Not Responding` in the title bar.  So an ERROR_TIMEOUT does not reliably indicate that the UI thread is trying to shut down unless you make uTimeout very large.  At least 10 seconds.  That kinda works, getting the occasional 10 second hang at exit is however not very pretty.

Solve this kind of problem for all the messages, not just WM_CLOSE.  WM_PAINT ought to be next, another one that's very, very hard to solve cleanly. Your worker thread asks to update the display a millisecond before the UI thread calls EndPaint().  And thus never displays the update, it simply gets lost.  A threading race, another standard threading bug.

The third classic threading bug is a *fire-hose* problem.  Happens when your worker thread produces results faster than the UI thread can handle them.  Very common, UI updates are pretty expensive.  Easy to detect, very hard to solve and unpredictable when it occurs.  Easy to detect because your UI will freeze, the UI thread burns 100% core trying to keep up with the message rate.  It doesn't get around to its low-priority tasks anymore.  Like painting.  Goes wrong *both* when you use SendMessage or PostMessage.  In the latter case you'll fill the message queue up to capacity.  It starts failing after it contains 10000 unprocessed messages.

Long story short, yes, SendMessage() is thread-safe.  But thread-safety is not a transitive property, it doesn't automatically make your own code thread-safe.  You still suffer from *all* the things that can go wrong when you use threads.  Deadlocks, races, fire-hosing.  Fear the threading beast.

Comment: So it's best not to use `SendMessage()`. But `PostMessage()` is asynchronous, so how can it be used to get the content of a UI control!

Comment: You should not write code like that, it is another threading race bug.  Collect the info from the UI before you start the worker thread.  Disable the window so that the user can't change the text and knows that editing cannot work.  Re-enable the window when the worker completes.

Comment: My worker thread does not terminate until the application is terminated. it must frequently get data from UI controls as well as display data to the UI controls.

Comment: The message ought to be crystal-clear by now: you are doing it wrong.  Finding a solution to the kind of problems you are dealing with by doing it your way is rather up to you, there is no universal one.  It is not impossible, you'll have to click the Ask Question button to describe your specific problem in detail.

Comment: @user4582812 You asked a broad and general question. And got an answer of the same nature. Next you start asking about the specifics of your app, which only you are aware of. If you want to ask about the specifics, do so, but it seems odd that you ask a general question, and then make comments on your specific problem. The conclusion you draw in your first comment is quite wrong. The world doesn't split into problems that are solved by calling `SendMessage`, and problems that are solved by calling `PostMessage`. That is a false dichotomy.

Comment: @David Heffernan You are right, sorry about that. I will start a new question for my specific problem.