# Using SendMessageToDescendants between threads

Tags: multithreading, winapi, mfc

In my MFC application I have a worker thread that listens on a network connection and as soon as some information has arrived I call `SendMessageToDescendants` to send that information via the lparam parameter. So every frame window will get the message and possibly process it via a message handler for the `WM_SYNCHRONOTIFICATION` message (`WM_SYNCHRONOTIFICATION` is a `WM_APP+x`  message).

**Code in the worker thread:** (simplified for brevity)

```
while (TRUE)
{
   CNotificationMessage notificationmessage;
   Listen(&notificationmessage);  // blocking until some information arrives

   m_pMainWnd->SendMessageToDescendants(WM_SYNCHRONOTIFICATION, NULL, (LPARAM)(newnotif));

   // have all OnSynchroNotification handlers been called here ?
}
```

**Message handler in the main thread:**

```
LRESULT CMyFrame::OnSynchroNotification(WPARAM p1, LPARAM p2)
{
  CNotificationMessage *pNotification = (CNotificationMessage*)p2;

  // process message (ommited for brevity)
}
```

The code works fine, but I'm not sure if upon return from `SendMessageToDescendants` all `OnSynchroNotification` have been called.

Comment: [Never use any SendMessage variety from a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29603742/17034).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to use is a counter. Before calling `SendMessage`, initialize a shared counter to the number of child windows you would like to have process the message. Each message handler is then responsible for decrementing the counter when it completes its work, and your event loop can check that the counter is 0 before generating more events. In pseudo C++:

```
unsigned int sharedCount; // global/static shared value

while (TRUE)
{
    CNotificationMessage notificationmessage;
    Listen(&notificationmessage);  // blocking until some information arrives

    unsigned int current = InterlockedCompareExchange(&sharedCount, activeWindowCount, 0);
    if (current == 0)
    {   
        m_pMainWnd->SendMessageToDescendants(WM_SYNCHRONOTIFICATION, NULL, (LPARAM)(newnotif));
    }
    else
    {
        // Still processing the last message.
    }

    while (InterlockedCompareExchange(&sharedCount, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

LRESULT CMyFrame::OnSynchroNotification(WPARAM p1, LPARAM p2)
{
    // Processing
    InterlockedDecrement(&sharedCount);
}
```

The slightly more complex solution, but the one I personally prefer, since you don't have to burn CPU waiting on completion, is to create an event for each message processing window, and then use [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) (or the Ex version) to halt the event loop until completion. Again, in pseudo C++:

```
while (TRUE)
{
    CNotificationMessage notificationmessage;
    Listen(&notificationmessage);  // blocking until some information arrives

    m_pMainWnd->SendMessageToDescendants(WM_SYNCHRONOTIFICATION, NULL, (LPARAM)(newnotif));

    DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(activeWindowCount, FrameEvents, TRUE, INFINITE);
    if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        // Success
    }
    else if (waitResult == WAIT_FAILED)
    {
        // Failure: Use GetLastError() to figure out why the function call failed.
    }

    // Reset the events
}    

LRESULT CMyFrame::OnSynchroNotification(WPARAM p1, LPARAM p2)
{
    // Processing
    SetEvent(thisFramesEvent);
}
```

This example uses an infinite timeout, but you can always set a reasonable timeout, and check for the return value `WAIT_TIMEOUT` to see if the time elapsed.

*(Required Disclaimer: Error checking and variable initialization have been removed from both of these for the sake of brevity and readability. See the documentation for how to check for errors.)*